# View live mynetworks config on postfix server

Tags: postfix

In my postfix config I have the following:

```
mynetworks = /etc/postfix/mynetworks
```

How can I view what postfix is currently using as the 'live' version of mynetworks?

I tried postconf, it only gives me the file name:

```
root@postfix:~# postconf -n |grep mynetworks
mynetworks = /etc/postfix/mynetworks
```

Comment: Why would you think that what Postfix currently uses is different then what's listed in the config file?

Comment: It seems to ignore new entries to that file. I suspect it requires a reload to pickup changes to the file. I want a way to compare the file to what postfix has in memory to verify that

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, I believe your actual problem is the following:

You always need to reload Postfix if you do changes to text config files, they only get read upon startup or reload (this is different for some tables and database backends that gets queried upon request).

So, if you change this file without a reload, the version in memory will be different.

Comment: So there is no way to print the contents of this variable at runtime?